# How to use mean squared prediction error (MSPE) with generated data?

Tags: regression, forecasting, mse

I came up with a linear model, estimated it on the training set and generated $m$ predictions with a seperate test set containing a sample size of $m$ (with the response variable not included in the test set).

Should I compute the [mean squared prediction error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_prediction_error) by subtracting the predictions from the mean of the $y$'s generated from the full test model ($y$'s generated by the test set with all the explanatory variables),
or should I use the mean of the predictions ($y$'s generated by the test set with the explanatory variables specified for that particular linear model),
or should I use the one with the minimum cv?